# Why does the well-ordering principle exclude $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

I was surprised I couldn't find an answer to this question. Simply put, why does the *well-ordering principle* exclude $0$? Is it just for cleaner notation (since we all recognize that $\mathbb Z^+ > 0$)?

i.e. if a set is a subset of $\{\{0\} \cup\mathbb Z^+\}$, this set still exhibits the well ordering property, right? ...and therefore still contains a least integer.

Edit: I guess the question is really, why doesn't the definition use the language of **non-negative integers**?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle): "the well-ordering principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element"...this definition matches that in my book (Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra)

Comment: Absolutely, since  what you denote $\{0\}\cup\mathbb Z^+$  is nothing else than $\mathbf N$.

Comment: @Bernard is there a reason that the definition uses $\mathbb Z^+$ instead of "non-negative integers"...semantics?

Comment: Do you have a link for this version of the well-ordering principle? (for me, it is a very general assertion from set theory.)

Comment: @Bernard my book (Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra) uses this definition...but for quicker access, even wikipedia uses this definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle

Comment: The principle doesn't exclude $0$, and really every set of integers bounded below satisfies it. Perhaps the author of your book is one of those people that don't like $0$ being a natural number, as opposed to other people, who like speaking the truth. ;)

Comment: @Bernard this is the first sentence of the wiki page: "the well-ordering principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element"

Comment: I think the problem is that depending on countries,  *positive* may mean $\ge 0$ or $>0$. For those which mean $\ge 0$, `> 0` is said to be *strictly positive*.

Comment: Tomorrow we can ask whether the set of integers ${}\ge -1$ has the well-ordering property.

Comment: @GEdgar it was a defintional question...I didn't know if I was missing some sort of nuance.

Comment: @Gae.S.: Of course the term “natural number” is human-defined, and as such the set of natural numbers contains exactly what we define to be in it. Of course we define it so that it is useful; but given that both the set of positive integers and the set of nonnegative integers are useful sets, there's no inherent reason to prefer to call one or the other “natural numbers”.

Comment: It's obvious that (i) WOP for the positive integers is equivalent to (ii) WOP for the non-negative integers. You see a place where (ii) is given and ask why it's not (i). If it were stated as (i) you could just as well ask why it's not (ii).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the motivation behind the question was that the author of my book introduced the concept during a section on integral domains (which contain the additive neutral element $0$). Therefore, it struck me as odd that the WOP would not be defined to include $0$, as that would be "more encompassing", so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a close relationship between the the ideas of:

The well-ordering principle

Mathematical induction

Proof by minimal counterexample

Fermat's method of infinite descent.

It is interesting that all of these *tend* to be expressed in terms of positive integers. In terms of infinite descent there is a very good reason for this since Fermat was concerned with positive integer solutions to equations. (Note how $a^p+b^p=c^p$ has infinitely many 
solutions for all primes $p$ if we allow zeroes!)

Given that infinite descent can be regarded as a forerunner of the other ideas it is only to be expected that all the ideas should be consistent regarding the issue of 'positive integers'.